# Backup & Restore on two different versions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup, restore

i have backup from sharepoint 2013 but sharepoint in **my virtual machine is 2016**.

is it possible **restore it on sp 2016**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , that's possible

- Restore your database.
- Go to SharePoint 2016 Central Administration, Application Management
  -> Manage Web Applications.
- Create a new web application.
- Complete new web application properties.
- Run the below SharePoint power shell commands as the administrator

  1. Test the content database

  > Test-SPContentDatabase -Name "DatabaseName"  -Web Application
  >   http://sitename

  2. Dismount the default created  database

  > Dismount-SPContentDatabase "DatabaseName"

  3. Attach SharePoint 2013 content database

  > Mount-SPContentDatabase "DatabaseName" -DatabaseServer "ServerName"
  >   -WebApplication http://sitename

Form More details , please check the below URL: 
[Upgrade databases from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-databases)